# Using WebRTC library with Visual c++

Tags: c++, windows, webrtc

I have built the WebRTC library by using this tutorial:
 https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/

Then I try to run this simple program on both Visual Studio 2013 Community and Visual Studio 2017 Professional:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jhPh.png)

However in both cases I have the same error:

> Error  LNK1107 invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x159BE command_line_parser.lib

I have tried to link to any possible webrtc *.lib files, but the problem still remains.

What is the correct way to link webrtc library to visual C++?

Comment: linker say to you that *command_line_parser.lib* is corrupted.

Comment: I try every single *.lib file (not just command_line_parser.lib) and it pops out the same error

Comment: of course. what you try is nonsense. the concrete file is corrupted. if you add another file to linker input - it not stop been coorupted

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: rebuild this lib. or download another

Answer (score 5):

You need cl.exe as compiler. Default by gn build prosess for generating the ninja files is set 'is_clang = true' and the clang.exe compiler is used.
please set in 'gn args --lists out/debug ' the parameter 'is_clang = false'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the linker, not with the compiler. you can link the webrtc .obj files but you can't link the webrtc .lib files.

I solve it with the GN build option "use_lld=false".